# groovy decimal string to integer

Tags: groovy, boomi

Hi All: I receive a decimal in string format and want to convert it to Integer in groovy. could not find any solution so far. For eg: I get the string value as "100.0" and I need the output as 100. Please help.

I plan to run this groovy script in boomi.

Answer (score 4):

First convert to float, then to integer:

```
def s = "100.0"
def f = s.toFloat()
def i = f.toInteger() //or (int)f
```

or one line,

```
def i = "100.0".toFloat().toInteger()
```